# sphinx apidoc/autodoc don't create 'submodules' and 'subpackages' groups in the sidebar or toc

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm using the sphinx-rtd-theme.  On both the sidebar and the TOCs of autodoc generated pages, directories and files  are grouped into special 'subpackages' and 'submodules' categories, like this:

```
my_package
    subpackages
        sp1
            submodules
                sp1_sm1
                sp1_sm2
        sp2
            submodules
                sp2_sm1
                sp2_sm2
    submodules
        sm1
        sm2
```

Is there a way to skip these groupings so that it's organized simply as:

```
my_package
    sp1
        sp1_sm1
        sp1_sm2
    sp2
        sp2_sm1
        sp2_sm2
    sm1
    sm2
```

Comment: I think you made a mistake when using [sphinx-apidoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#cmdoption-sphinx-apidoc-E) that headers saying `subpackages` and `submodules` were automatically inserted into the `.rst` files when you generated them? You'll have to delete those headers manually or regenerate the `.rst` files. That isn't a theme issue because the theme will render the headers as they are in the reStructuredText files.

Comment: @bad_coder thanks for point out the `-E` argument, but even with it, it's still generating "Submodules" and "Subpackages" headings automatically in the rst files.  Manually editing them is an option, but largely defeats the purpose of using autodoc.

Comment: Those headings that are still generated have to be removed by hand. The only tool to generate `.rst` files is `sphinx-apidoc` (don't confuse it with `autodoc` that's a different tool!) so you're out of options (other than writing the files yourself). The point of  `sphinx-apidoc` is that you only use it once at the beginning of the project and afterwards you maintain the `.rst` files.

Comment: Depending on your needs you could rewrite [`sphinx-apidoc`'s templates](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#cmdoption-sphinx-apidoc-t). But you'll have to decide if it's worth the extra trouble or if that's just more work.